# PHP only sending one mail() in a page

Tags: php, html, email

All of sudden, my PHP code that sends an email after someone registers on a form stopped working. I'm cracking my head trying to figure out what is going on...

I already tested a little piece of code emailing myself and it works.
I observed the console window in Chrome while the page executes, but it doesn't show any errors.

The code sends me an email with the form info and sends an email to the user's inbox telling that the registration was successful.

```
// SENDING EMAIL

//To me
$line_break = "\r\n";
$emailSender = "subscriptions@mydomain.com";
$emailTOme = "me@mydomain.com";
$cco = "support@mydomain.com";
$subject= "my subject";
$messageHTML = '
    <p>Nome.......: ' . $nome . '</p>
    <p>E-mail.......: '.$email . ' </p>
    <p>Profissão.......: '. $profissao . '  </p>
    <p>Endereço.....: '. $endereco . ', ' . $endereco_num . ' </p>
    <p>Complemento.....: '. $complemento . '</p>
    <p>Bairro.......: ' . $bairro . ' </p>
    <p>CEP..........: '. $cep . ' </p>
    <p>Cidade.......: ' . $cidade . ' </p>
    <p>UF...........: ' . $uf . ' </p>
    <p>Telefone.....: ' . $telefone . ' </p>
    <p>Celular......: ' . $celular . ' </p>
    <p>Inscrição p/.: ' . $evento . '</p>
    <p>Valor da inscrição: <b>R$' . $valor_inscricao . '</b></p>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.1" . $line_break;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". $line_break;
$headers .= "From: " . $emailSender . $line_break;
$headers .= "Return-Path: " . $emailSender . $line_break;
$headers .= "Bcc: " . $cco . $line_break;
$headers .= "Reply-to: " .  $emailSender . $line_break;

mail($emailTOme , $subject, $messageHTML,$headers, $emailSender);  

//email for the user
$messageHTMLuser = '
    <p> Lorem </p>
    <p> Ipsum </b></p>';


$headers2 = "MIME-Version: 1.1" . $line_break;
$headers2 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1". $line_break;
$headers2 .= "From: " . $emailSender . $line_break;
$headers2 .= "Return-Path: " . $emailSender . $line_break;
$headers2 .= "Reply-to: " .  $emailSender . $line_break;

mail($email, 'We recieved your registration', $messageHTMLuser, $headers2, $emailSender);
```

The problem is that now only the second `mail()` function works.

The `$email` on the second function comes from the previous form.

Comment: Chrome console window would only show Javascript/network errors, not PHP errors.

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking inside the error log?

Comment: Looks like the BCC line on the first $header is the problem... But it always worked! Any ideas why it stopped ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to comment out the "BCC" line.

As the current php mail don't support this option (anymore) - apparantly as a way to avoid bcc-form-spamers..

In order to use advanced email functions, you would probably be better off using PHPMailer (or a similar lib): https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Comment: @Reto all your code variation are ultimately exactly the same code as the code in the question. They cannot possibly change anything. Can you explain why you think your changes might help in any way?

Comment: As i mentioned - it could be a sort of bcc-form-spam-protection  the PHP-way ;)

Comment: The link you provided has no connection to the question or to your answer. My point was that `$headers .= 'Bcc: support@mydomain.com'. $line_break;` (your answer) and `$cco = "support@mydomain.com"; $headers .= "Bcc: " . $cco . $line_break;` (the OP version) are EXACTLY the same, the headers will be exactly the same. Evan after all your edits, your answer is still showing code that will produce the exact same output as the code in the OP.

Comment: I hard coded `$headers .= 'Bcc: support@mydomain.com'. $line_break;` and it didn't work...

Comment: @Reto now you edited your answer and made it even more confusing, by adding two contradicting suggestions: comment out the Bcc line versus keeping the Bcc line but "hardcoding" it. @LucasM. please see my previous comment, 'hardcoding' will not accomplish anything, use `var_dump($headers)` and see they are EXACTLY the same regardless of the suggestions from this answer.

Comment: @Reto you should post this as a comment. An answer should explain how it works, why and mention the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the start of your script and it should show you your errors (if any) at the top of the page.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```